# Select inner join returns wrong result

Tags: sql, inner-join

I'm using select inner join as below. How do I get my expected result?

Here is the sql syntax:

```
select tgr.id, tgr.venid, sum(tgrd.qty*tgrd.pri), sum(tgrp.amo)
from tgr inner join tgrd on tgr.id = tgrd.id
inner join tgrp on tgr.id = tgrp.id
where tgr.id = 3
group by tgr.id, tgr.venid
having sum(tgrd.qty*tgrd.pri)-sum(tgrp.amo)>0;
```

result:

```
3 | 1 | 462000 | 262000
```

but I'm expecting result:

```
3 | 1 | 231000 | 131000
```

source from 3 tables: tgr, tgrd, tgrp

```
tgr table
id  venid
3   1

tgrd table
id  plu qty pri
3   2   2.7 45000
3   1   7.3 15000

tgrp table
id  type  amo
3   2     0
3   2     131000
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Joining Many to many relationships and group by is a bit tricky. Consider aggregation before the joining.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS This seems likely to be a common error where people want the join on a shared key of some aggregations (each possibly involving joining) but they erroneously try to do all the joining then all the aggregating or to aggregate over previous aggregations.

Comment: @ jarlh, I was still figuring out what you meant with 'Consider aggregation before the joining' then I saw the answer below which I think that what you meant. Now I've learnt at least 1 more trick with sql syntax. :)

Comment: @ philipxy, I thought I've removed lot of garbage to fit SSCCE. I'm not sure there is any that I can still remove. Cant do anything on SQL syntax. Actual and desired result are put at most minimal. I think what you meant by minimal reproducible is that I replace source with 'create table' and 'insert into'. Please correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have a many-to-many relationship from `tgr` to `tgrd` and `tgrp`, you need to perform aggregation before `JOIN`ing the tables, otherwise you can double (or more) count each value. This query will give you the results you want:

```
select tgr.id, tgr.venid, total, amo
from tgr 
inner join (select id, sum(qty*pri) as total
            from tgrd
            group by id) tgrd on tgr.id = tgrd.id
inner join (select id, sum(amo) as amo
            from tgrp
            group by id) tgrp on tgr.id = tgrp.id
where tgr.id = 3
group by tgr.id, tgr.venid
having total - amo > 0;
```

Output:

```
id  venid   total       amo
3   1       231000.00   131000
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cZqdDQhgHYSeHVUKKXdA5K/0)

Comment: This answer solves the problem. Greatly appreciated. :)